# RuntimeError: Event loop is closed (python 3.8)

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-3.8

Running the below code is throwing runtime error, As the event loop is still not closed from the print statement before the loop is closed explicitly

```
import time
import asyncio


def blocking():
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print(f"{time.ctime()} Hello from a thread!")


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

loop.run_in_executor(None, blocking)

pending = asyncio.all_tasks(loop=loop)
for task in pending:
    task.cancel()
group = asyncio.gather(*pending, return_exceptions=True)
loop.run_until_complete(group)
print(asyncio.get_event_loop().is_closed()) # returns false
loop.close()
```

What am I missing ? (Did the main thread close the loop before the blocking function code ran?)

Comment: You can't call `asyncio.gather` without `await`-ing on it, and you can only do that inside of an async coroutine. You would need to move a chunk of your logic into an async coroutine for any of this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `loop.run_in_executor(None, blocking)` call doesn't create a task in the loop, but only returns a future, with the work being immediately submitted to the executor.

Because of this, `asyncio.all_tasks` returns nothing, and even if the future was returned, you can't cancel it after it's started as it's wrapping a [`concurrent.futures.Future`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future.cancel).

As the executor is started, it does your sleep while the main thread continues and closes the loop, then after it finishes, asyncio tries to set the returned result on the `Future` it returned which fails.